# Optional matches in structural pattern matching

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable `data` incoming from a websocket and I'm using match/case to determine what to do with it. It's coming in as a tuple as below, but I want to match both of these the same.

```
data = ("foo", )
# or
data = ("foo", {"bar": 213})
```

Some cases I need the data, others I don't. In the case I don't need it (i.e. the case above where the first element is foo) I just want to essentially ignore the second variable if it's present.

This is my current way of doing this but am I going about it wrong? Or is there a more succinct form?

```
match data:
        case ["foo"] | ["foo", _]:
            ...
        case ["baz", x]:
            ...
        ...
```

Comment: `case ['foo', *_]` or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @SUTerliakov actually didn't think that was going to work in the case where there was only one element. I didn't even give it a try because so. Works perfectly! Post as an answer and I will mark it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with star unpacking, variable (or underscore) with a star matches zero or more items. So the following will work:

```py
data = ['foo']

match data:
    case ['foo', *_]:
        print('Matched')
```

It is similar to common iterable unpacking:

```
a, *b = [1]
assert a == 1
assert b == []
```

**Note:** it is different from your original code, because `['foo', {}, {}]` will be matched too. There is no analogue of regex `?` quantifier, so "no more than one" cannot be expressed this way.

Comment: Thanks for including that note in the answer. Again, don't know why I didn't think of this. But if I didn't then I'm sure others will too. (maybe)